# Range of numbers in a row in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to fill in a row with the following range in each cell:
1-5, 6-10, 11-15,..., 596-600

i.e 1-5 in 1st cell of the row, 6-10 in the 2nd cell of the row and so on.

Is there some formula or some functionality in Google sheets to do this?

Sorry if this is a silly question. I don't really use spreadsheets much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=ArrayFormula(SEQUENCE(1,10,1,5)&"-"&SEQUENCE(1,10,5,5))
```

[image: Google sheets use of sequence]

Or maybe:

```
=ArrayFormula(SEQUENCE(10,1,1,5)&"-"&SEQUENCE(10,1,5,5))
```

[image: Google sheets use of sequence]

You can even try:

```
=ArrayFormula(SEQUENCE(10,5,1,5)&"-"&SEQUENCE(10,5,5,5))
```

[image: Google sheets use of sequence]

Please read more about [`SEQUENCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(ROW(A1:A600), MOD(ROW(A1:A600), 5)=0)-4&"-"&
 FILTER(ROW(A1:A600), MOD(ROW(A1:A600), 5)=0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In cell A1, type "1-5."
In cell A2, use the formula:

> =ROW(A1)*5+1&"-"&ROW(A1)*5+5

Copy that formula down to the remaining rows.